# How to Show Data In Two Line in Drop Down (Select Box) Using JS or CSS Basis of the Data

Tags: css

I have this data in dropdown (select box) 
On change of value data which i selected should be shown in two lines. in same dropdown.

```
<select id="q1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?</option>
    <option value="2">In what city or town did your mother and father meet?</option>
    <option value="3">In what city or town was your first job?</option>
    <option value="4">What is the middle name of your oldest child?</option>
    <option value="5">What is your maternal grandmothers maiden name?</option>
    <option value="6">What is your oldest cousins first and last name?</option>
    <option value="7">What school did you attend for sixth grade?</option>
</select>
```

On change of value it should show in two line if data in not able to fit in single line.
Otherwise it should appear in single line.
I am using this CSS :-

```
select {
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
    border-top: 0 none;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase what it should do `on change`, because it makes no sense.

Comment: On change of value data which i selected should be shown in two lines. in same dropdown.

Comment: Do not use max-width.

Answer (score 0):

adding below code to select css will display the content in multiple lines.

```
word-break: break-word;
white-space: normal;
```

```css
select {
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
    border-top: 0 none;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<select id="q1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?</option>
    <option value="2">In what city or town did your mother and father meet?</option>
    <option value="3">In what city or town was your first job?</option>
    <option value="4">What is the middle name of your oldest child?</option>
    <option value="5">What is your maternal grandmothers maiden name?</option>
    <option value="6">What is your oldest cousins first and last name?</option>
    <option value="7">What school did you attend for sixth grade?</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/243p5fzd/6/

```
select {
   border-left: 0 none;
   border-right: 0 none;
   border-top: 0 none;
   min-height: 30px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   text-align: left;
   max-width: 200px;
   word-break: break-word;
   overflow-wrap: break-word; /*Mozilla */
   white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
   white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
   word-wrap: break-word;
```

}